# git executable in Anaconda causes "fork bomb"

Tags: git, conda, msys2

I'm running MSYS2 on a Windows 10 machine with Anaconda Python installed in my home directory under `~/Apps/`. When I installed MSYS2 some time ago, I followed the procedure [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Install-inside-MSYS2-proper) to install the `git` executable from Git for Windows "inside" MSYS2, so when I open the MINGW64 shell, I see the Git for Windows version of `git` as follows

```
(base) ~ $ git --version
git version 2.44.0.rc0.windows.1
```

(The "windows" in the version string comes from Git for Windows.)

However, as of yesterday, `git --version` causes an error message about a "fork bomb", something I've never seen before. Here's what happens,

```
(base) ~ $ git --version
BUG (fork bomb): C:\<path to home>\Apps\Anaconda3\Library\bin\git.exe
(base) ~ $ which -a git
/c/<path to home>/Apps/Anaconda3/Library/bin/git
/mingw64/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
(base) ~ $ conda deactivate
~ $ git --version
git version 2.44.0.rc0.windows.1
```

Once I do `conda deactivate`, I have a functioning `git` again.

This error seems to have cropped up after an update with `pacman -Syu`. Whenever I run this command, I get the following warning,

```
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "libcurl"
warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "curl"
warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "libcurl"
warning: cannot resolve "libcrypt", a dependency of "openssh"
:: The following packages cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      curl  libcurl  openssh

:: Do you want to skip the above packages for this upgrade? [Y/n]
```

I usually answer "Y". I'm not sure what the eventual consequences of skipping these upgrades are, but perhaps my last upgrade caused this "fork bomb"? And what is a "fork bomb"?

**Edit**: Switching to another `conda` environment hides the Anaconda `git`,

```
(base) ~ $ conda activate flask
(flask) ~ $ git --version
git version 2.44.0.rc0.windows.1
```

Doing `which -a git` at this point shows that the Anaconda `git` is no longer on the path. This doesn't tell me what is happening when the Anaconda `git` is on the path, and I don't want to fiddle with the Anaconda `git` unless I know what is happening; i.e. I know what "fork bomb" means. Some kind of recursion between `git` functions?

Comment: By https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-discussions/BUG-FORK-BOMB/td-p/2003754 and https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/foFlnDd3VJo, you could try to reinstall git and maybe recreate the `.git` folder if you have one in the said directory.

Comment: Anaconda installed its own `git`; I didn't. I don't know what Anaconda uses it for. Also, I executed the `git --version` commands in my home directory, which does not have a `.git/` subdirectory. That is, my home directory is not a Git repository.